# Get url from webbrowser in python

Tags: python

I would like to ask how can I get list of urls which are opened in my webbrowser, from example in firefox. I need it in Python.
Thanks

Comment: Are you asking for your web browser's history, or a way to open a list of urls in your web browser?

Answer (score 0):

Try either SeleniumRC - which is very good

or  https://github.com/bard/mozrepl/wiki/

You can use it with python as described here

http://www.craigethomas.com/blog/2009/04/get-android-market-stats-with-python-mozrepl-and-beautifulsoup/

But I would go the selenium route for anything not trivial

Answer (score 0):

First I'd check if the browser has some kind of command line argument which could print such informations. I only checked Opera and it doesn't have one. What you could do is parse session file. I'd bet that every browser stores list of opened tabs/windows on disk (so it could recover after crash). Opera has this information in `~/.opera/sessions/autosave.win`. It's pretty straight-forward text file. Find other browsers' session files in .mozzila, .google, etc.. or if you are on windows in /user/ directories. There might be commands to ask running instance for its working directory (as you can specify it on startup and it doesn't have to be the default one).

That's the way I'd go. Might be the wrong one.